# How do I ge the `Token Record` account for a pNFT

Tags: rust, metaplex, metadata, mpl-token-metadata

Is there a way to access a programmable NFT's `Token Record` Data using anchor in Rust?

Is there a function for this provided by the Metaplex SDK? I have the address of the account and I just need to get the data?

Comment: Can you offer a bit more about the context you need this? Is it in a Solana program, or some other environment that is written in Rust?

Comment: I want the data contained in the `delegate` field  contained in the `Token Record` account.

I am writing a program in anchor, and I want to delegate the pNFT to a pda derived in the program.

Comment: Does the answer I posted below offer enough info or is there still something missing?

Answer (score 2):

You can using `TokenRecord::from_account_info()`. Make sure to import the `TokenMetadataAccount` trait as well.

```
use mpl_token_metadata::state::{TokenRecord, TokenMetadataAccount};
```

You use it like so:

```
let my_token_record = TokenRecord::from_account_info(&ctx.accounts.token_record_account);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is a function for it in meta plex sdk. But in general for anchor programs you can get the data via connection.getAccountInfo(yourAddress) then if it is part of the meta plex program you can decode it something like this:

```
    const decoded = program.coder.accounts.decode(
      "yourAccountName",
      accountInfo.data
    )
```

Comment: is there a way I could do it in Rust?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you load account in your instruction accounts struct with the TokenRecord (otherwise you'll be trying to access an account that is not accessible), then you can have that account validated and deserialized by anchor in the instruction function.

```
pub struct IxAccounts {
   ...
   tokenRecord: Account<'info, TokenRecord>,
   ...
}

pub fn ix(ctx: IxAccounts) {
   let delegate = ctx.accounts.tokenRecord.delegate;
   ...
}
```

[TokenRecord struct from sdk](https://docs.rs/mpl-token-metadata/latest/mpl_token_metadata/state/struct.TokenRecord.html)

Comment: thanks. `TokenRecordAccount` type was recently added to anchor. 

using the TokenRecord from mpl-token-metadata will break with anchor because of the borsh dep mismatch.